# Can macros in C++ define macros?

Tags: c++, macros, g++

I was wondering if it was possible to define a macro in C++ that defines another macro that can be used in later code. Is this possible, or is the preprocessor used by g++ too limited for this?

Comment: It's nor the "preprocesor used by g++" that isn't powerful enough, it's the C++ language itself that does not allow this. If you explained what you want to accomplish, I'm sure people here could come up with a solution.

Comment: How would you be "limited" by this?  Share what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot define a macro within the expansion of another macro.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't define a macro as a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, its not exactly what you are looking for, but it might help.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_MACRO_1
#define PRINT_MACRO(varName)   \
        std::cout<<varName<<std::endl;
#else
#define PRINT_MACRO(varName)   \
        //do nothing
#endif
```

So you can define a macro depending on another preprecursor condition which was defined defined.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor makes only one pass over the source code, so this is not possible. However, you could use an external tool to perform some preprocessing ahead of compilation, like [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/).